# Multi serialPort connection

Tags: c#, arduino, serial-port

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.IO.Ports;
using System.IO;
using System.Threading;

namespace wangxl{
public partial class Smart_meter : Form
{
    public int begin_year;
    public int begin_month;
    public int begin_day;
    public int finish_year;
    public int finish_month;
    public int finish_day;
    string from_bs_2;
    string from_EM;
    double[,] power = new double[4, 23];
    int chushihua = 0;
    int chuqi_changshu = 0;
    int n_1 = 0;
    int n_2 = 0;
    double[,] power_display_f = new double[4, 23];
    string path =   "C:\\Users\\Public\\data\\data_logging.txt";
    string path_m = "C:\\Users\\Public\\data\\energy_monitoring.txt";
    //  string path = "‪C:\\energy_moniotring\\data_logging.txt";   

    public Smart_meter()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        String[] input = SerialPort.GetPortNames();
        comboBox1.Items.AddRange(input);
        comboBox16.Items.AddRange(input);
    }

void button1(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            serialPort1.PortName = comboBox1.Text;
            serialPort1.BaudRate = Convert.ToInt32(comboBox2.Text);
            serialPort1.DataBits = Convert.ToInt32(comboBox3.Text);
            serialPort1.StopBits = (StopBits)Enum.Parse(typeof(StopBits),     comboBox4.Text);
            serialPort1.Parity = (Parity)Enum.Parse(typeof(Parity), comboBox5.Text);
            serialPort1.Open();
            progressBar1.Value = 100;
        }

        catch (Exception err)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(err.Message, "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
        }
    }

    private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (serialPort1.IsOpen)
        {
            serialPort1.Close();
            progressBar1.Value = 0;
        }
    }

    private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (serialPort1.IsOpen)
        {
            string output;
            output = textBox2.Text;
            serialPort1.Write(output);
            textBox2.Text = "";
            from_bs_2 = "";
            serialPort1.DiscardOutBuffer();
            //     serialPort1.DiscardOutBuffer();
        }
    }

    void button7_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {  
            serialPort2.PortName = comboBox16.Text;
            serialPort2.BaudRate = Convert.ToInt32(comboBox15.Text);
            serialPort2.DataBits = Convert.ToInt32(comboBox13.Text);
            serialPort2.StopBits = (StopBits)Enum.Parse(typeof(StopBits), comboBox14.Text);
            serialPort2.Parity = (Parity)Enum.Parse(typeof(Parity), comboBox12.Text);
            serialPort2.Open();
            progressBar2.Value = 100;
        }
        catch (Exception err)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(err.Message, "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
        }
    }
    private void button8_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (serialPort2.IsOpen)
        {
        serialPort2.Close();
        progressBar2.Value = 0;
        }
    }

    private void serialPort1_DataReceived(object sender, SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e)
    {
        Thread.Sleep(1000);  // important
        from_bs_2 += serialPort1.ReadExisting();
        Thread.Sleep(1000);
        this.Invoke(new EventHandler(showdata));
        Thread.Sleep(1000);
    }

    private void serialPort2_DataReceived(object sender, SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e)
    {
        Thread.Sleep(1000);  // important
        from_EM += serialPort2.ReadExisting();
        Thread.Sleep(1000);
        this.Invoke(new EventHandler(showdata_2));
        Thread.Sleep(1000);
        //  textBox1.Text += "laishujule";
    }
```

I want to design a program which can connect 2 or 3 Arduinos at same time. So, I created a serialPort 1, it works well, I can receive the data from serial 1, but when I use the same way to create serialPort 2, I find the serialPort doesn't work, it can be connected, but it can't get any data from Arduino. I found that the `serialPort2_DataReceived` function doesn't work, I had add the serialPort 2 into my program from tools. Can you help me?

Comment: I run multiple serial ports all the time, and the datareceived events work for all of them.  When you say "I found the serialport2_datarecieved function doesnt work", how do you know it doesn't work?  Do both arduinos have their own COM Port #?  Can you verify the arduino is sending data?

Answer (score 0):

In your code, you are not specifying the SerialDataReceivedEventHandler for each SerialPort. Try adding the lines in your code before opening the serial:

```
serialPort1.DataReceived += new SerialDataReceivedEventHandler(serialPort1_DataReceived);
serialPort2.DataReceived += new SerialDataReceivedEventHandler(serialPort2_DataReceived);

void button1(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        serialPort1.PortName = comboBox1.Text;
        serialPort1.BaudRate = Convert.ToInt32(comboBox2.Text);
        serialPort1.DataBits = Convert.ToInt32(comboBox3.Text);
        serialPort1.StopBits = (StopBits)Enum.Parse(typeof(StopBits),     comboBox4.Text);
        serialPort1.Parity = (Parity)Enum.Parse(typeof(Parity), comboBox5.Text);
        serialPort1.DataReceived += new SerialDataReceivedEventHandler(serialPort1_DataReceived);
        serialPort1.Open();
        progressBar1.Value = 100;
    }

    catch (Exception err)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(err.Message, "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
    }
}
void button7_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {  
        serialPort2.PortName = comboBox16.Text;
        serialPort2.BaudRate = Convert.ToInt32(comboBox15.Text);
        serialPort2.DataBits = Convert.ToInt32(comboBox13.Text);
        serialPort2.StopBits = (StopBits)Enum.Parse(typeof(StopBits), comboBox14.Text);
        serialPort2.Parity = (Parity)Enum.Parse(typeof(Parity), comboBox12.Text);
        serialPort2.DataReceived += new SerialDataReceivedEventHandler(serialPort2_DataReceived);
        serialPort2.Open();
        progressBar2.Value = 100;
    }
    catch (Exception err)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(err.Message, "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
    }
}
```